# Are flights actually cheaper *to book* during the week?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, tickets, seasonal

Last week I was eyeing up flights to Vegas from Vancouver.  I had vaguely chosen the flight that I wanted. On Saturday I found that the flights I wanted weren't there, and in general, it was more expensive than before.  I checked again on Sunday, same thing.  I then remembered some anecdotal statement that airlines put prices up on weekends.

Monday was a public holiday, so I wasn't sure how that would go. Sure enough, flights were still up, but this could be just that all flights had gone up in price.

Come Tuesday, back to work, and I checked. The flight that I'd been eyeing up the previous week was back down to the price I wanted, and more cheap flights were available.

Of course, this is only one anecdotal moment. Are there studies or statements from airlines online somewhere where there's documented evidence that they do this on purpose?

(Further anecdotal evidence will not be accepted as an answer)

Comment: As this is anecdotal I'm putting it as a comment not an answer: I saw the exact same thing when booking a few tickets on a flight a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Recently I monitored a specific domestic trip in Australia every day or two for about a month trying to get cheaper flights.  There was no change from weekend to weekday, but that is in the context of a very specific market.

Comment: As one of the travel agents explained to me some time back the reason for expenses on Friday and Sunday is business travelers.  Business trip starts on Monday so they fly in on Sunday to get settled and fly back on Friday.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just reading an [article on Mashable](http://mashable.com/2012/07/26/cheap-airfare/): "The [FareCompare](http://www.farecompare.com/) travel gurus suggest it's best to buy airplane tickets mid-day on a Tuesday or Wednesday."

Comment: FareCompare did their research. I doubt whether it's actually statistically *significant* though. In my own experience, monday is the best day (international flights) see http://www.farecompare.com/travel-advice/tips-from-air-travel-insiders/

Comment: Crud, I read the same mashable article, can't believe I missed that comment :/

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I read the article literally minutes after seeing your question. :)