# What's the best day of the week to buy airfare?

Tags: air-travel, budget

Is there any day of the week when airfares are statistically the cheapest to buy?

Comment: I was sure we had this question already, but can't find it.  Great q!

Comment: I'm sure too. I remember answering it, even.

Comment: And here it is: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8803/are-flights-actually-cheaper-to-book-during-the-week/8807#8807

Comment: Argh, I'd just come back to post it, and MastaBaba beat me: [Are flights actually cheaper *to book* during the week?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8803/101)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A number of people will tell you different things, but I'll say Tuesday or Wednesday.

Now, there are two parts to this question.  Firstly, what day is the cheapest to **fly**, and then what day is the cheapest to **buy**.

To fly, is generally during the week days, not Monday or Friday as people are coming back / going on trips - leisure or business. Morning/evening flights are more expensive, etc etc.

Now, the key part you're asking is when do you buy.

Firstly, [NOT the weekends.  It's been shown](http://www.petergreenberg.com/2008/03/06/the-best-day-of-the-week-to-buy-cheap-tickets/), and I've seen personally, that airline ticket prices will often rise on the weekend, then drop again on Monday.  The theory being that more people shop for tickets on the weekend.  Annoying, but there you go.

Now, the best day?  It's going to be Tuesday or Wednesday, depending on a few factors.

[Travelocity's Director of Flights, Dominique Philips, says](http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/is-there-a-best-day-of-the-week-to-book-airfare.html?id=1290508) that most airlines tend to release sales on Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays

**Tuesday**

[John Morrey, vice president of retail air at Expedia](http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/is-there-a-best-day-of-the-week-to-book-airfare.html?id=1290508) says in his opinion, booking on Tuesday evenings is ideal. He notes that airlines tend to release fare sales on Tuesday mornings, and if other carriers match, they usually do so by the evening. Fare sales generally end on Fridays, and Morrey says, "In addition, when airlines raise fares, they tend to do this on a weekend, so Saturdays and Sundays [are] less attractive."

[The CEO of Farecompare.com, Rick Seaney](http://abcnews.go.com/Travel/best-day-buy-airline-tickets-secrets-finding-cheap/story?id=10737207#.UNTZp3f4J8E), states:

> The best day to shop for airfare is Tuesday. And let me get even more
>   specific: shop on Tuesday at about 3 p.m.

He's so emphatic about this, that he has an [entire article devoted to it](http://abcnews.go.com/Travel/best-day-buy-cheap-airfare-secrets-deals-airline/story?id=9601203&page=1#.UNTb8Hf4J8F).

**Wednesday**

[PeterGreenberg.com says](http://www.petergreenberg.com/2008/03/06/the-best-day-of-the-week-to-buy-cheap-tickets/):

> By late Monday, depending on how that new fare is doing in the
>   marketplace, Airline C might jump into the battle and offer an even
>   lower fare, so look for all the other airlines to rush to match that
>   one – usually by Tuesday – and the war is on. Prices might go even
>   lower on Wednesday. And that’s when you strike.
>
> Wait any longer than Wednesday, and you may be in trouble. The wars
>   usually end by Thursday morning. Why? Friday is just around the
>   corner! And the cycle starts all over again.

[EHow.com claims that](http://www.ehow.com/how_4610673_pick-day-week-book-flight.html):

> Log on to the airline's website shortly after 12am (in the airline's
>   time zone) on Wednesday night. This is the best day and time of the
>   week to book a flight because this is when most airlines purge their
>   computerized systems of any airline reservations that were not booked.

**Conclusion**

So it depends a little on what you're searching for.  For upcoming weekend flights, you should probably consider booking on Wednesdays.  For far-ahead (not this weekend) flights, the release times described on Tuesdays seems to be the way to go :)

Comment: This conventional wisdom is [being challenged](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-best-days-to-book-airfare-2013-1)...

Comment: How do I know the airline's time zone? For example, flying from Brazil to New Zealand via Emirates. Is it the time zone of the Brazilian branch? Or in the United Arab Emirates?

Comment: @Roberto when I wrote this I'd have said UAE, but now I'd say check Emirates.co.nz and Emirates.com.br as well to check.

Answer (score 2):

## Cheapest day of week to

### book

[Expedia's 2023 Air Travel Hacks Report](https://www.expedia.com/stories/2023-flight-hacks/) says:

> **Book on a Sunday to save up to 15% on average**<sup>3</sup> Travelers who book on Sundays instead of Fridays tend to save, on average, around 5% on domestic flights and 15% on international flights. While the best day of the week to book has been Sunday for the past four years, travelers saved 5% more on average in 2022 compared to 2021.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>3.  Best day of the week to book recommendation is based on average round-trip ticket prices for flights originating in the US for January through August 2022, sourced from ARC’s global airline sales database. Percentages noted are averages.</sup>

### fly

> **Depart on a Wednesday to save up to 15% on average**<sup>7</sup>  In general, travelers who started a trip on a Wednesday, versus the beginning of the week (a Sunday or a Monday) saved, on average, 15% on domestic flights. For international flights, travelers who departed on a Wednesday instead of during the weekend (a Sunday or a Saturday) saved 10% on average.