# When to buy plane tickets to get best rates?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, planning, price

I'm planning a trip from Europe to USA, that will happen next summer.

I was looking lately into purchasing plane tickets, but a lot of carriers do not offer late July/early August 2015 tickets *yet*.

So, I can buy some ticket on kayak.com, but I feel that if I'll wait a bit, I might get a better deal. My question is generally - when is the best moment to purchase tickets - one that gives best prices, but also doesn't limit available flights too much, so I have options to choose from.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11322/444

Comment: I was more looking in terms of "how many days/weeks/months earlier to buy". I know I have to fly on saturdays both ways (due to work schedule, and duration of flight), so I can't realistically change that.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, but I think the answer would apply fully to your question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2952/444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to cheapair.com](http://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/when-should-you-buy-your-airline-ticket-heres-what-our-data-has-to-say/), it's 54 days in advance. At least in 2013 it was. Quoting the article,

> [They] monitored 4,191,533 trips. For each trip – that is, a flight from city A to city B on a specific date with a specific trip length– we looked at prospective fares over about a 10½ month booking window, ranging from 320 days in advance, to 1 day in advance, including every possible booking date in between. It adds up to a database of 1.3 billion air fares — and a serious headache for those who were tasked with making sense of it!